# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'auth.tenanatId') in firebase react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

i am making a authentication app in react native with firebase and i get this error in the sign up process called undefined is not an object (evaluating 'auth.tenantId') i cant figure this out i am using react native can any of you please help me fix this error

this is my error screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mupat.png

this is my code

```
import { Text, View, TextInput, ImageBackground, Button, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform } from 'react-native';
import AppStyles from '../styles/AppStyles';
import InlineTextButton from '../Components/InlineTextButton';
import React from 'react';
import { auth } from "firebase/app";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, sendEmailVerification } from "firebase/auth";

export default function SignUp({ navigation }) {
  const background = require("../assets/background.jpg");

  let [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  let [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  let [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = React.useState("");
  let [validationMessage, setValidationMessage] = React.useState("");

  let validateAndSet = (value, valueToCompare, setValue) => {
    if (value !== valueToCompare) {
      setValidationMessage("Passwords do not match.");
    } else {
      setValidationMessage("");
    }

    setValue(value);
  };

  let signUp = () => {
    if (password === confirmPassword) {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser);
        navigation.navigate("ToDo", { user: userCredential.user });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setValidationMessage(error.message);
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <ImageBackground style={AppStyles.imageContainer} source={background}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView 
        style={AppStyles.backgroundCover} 
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={60}>
        <Text style={[AppStyles.lightText, AppStyles.header]}>Sign Up</Text>
        <Text style={[AppStyles.errorText]}>{validationMessage}</Text>
        <TextInput 
          style={[AppStyles.textInput, AppStyles.lightTextInput, AppStyles.lightText]} 
          placeholder='Email' 
          placeholderTextColor="#BEBEBE"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={setEmail} />
        <TextInput 
          style={[AppStyles.textInput, AppStyles.lightTextInput, AppStyles.lightText]} 
          placeholder='Password' 
          placeholderTextColor="#BEBEBE" 
          secureTextEntry={true} 
          value={password} 
          onChangeText={(value) => validateAndSet(value, confirmPassword, setPassword)} />
        <TextInput 
          style={[AppStyles.textInput, AppStyles.lightTextInput, AppStyles.lightText]} 
          placeholder='Confirm Password' 
          placeholderTextColor="#BEBEBE" 
          secureTextEntry={true} 
          value={confirmPassword} 
          onChangeText={(value) => validateAndSet(value, password, setConfirmPassword)} />
        <View style={[AppStyles.rowContainer, AppStyles.topMargin]}>
          <Text style={AppStyles.lightText}>Already have an account? </Text>
          <InlineTextButton text="Login" onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()} />
        </View>
        <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={signUp} color="#f7b267" />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

i dont know why this is hapening i am expecting after this error is solved when i click the sign up button it would crete the user account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using firebase 9?

You should do it like this:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

You must send auth as a param but don't import it, instead of that use  `const auth = getAuth()`
as you see in the example